# Wordpress custom post type with meta - how to retrieve with wp_query

Tags: wp-query

I developed simple plugin and now would like to get only posts where start_date < $now & end_date > $now so I have to add meta_query to the args but how should it look like?

```
        $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'startdate',
                'value' => $Now,
                'compare' => '<',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
            // 'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key' => 'enddate',
                'value' => $Now,
                'compare' => '>',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
        ),
);
```

I think I got this :)